# ASP.Net MVC Bootstrap Grid Not Working Properly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 in my project. The problem is that the grid is not working properly.

I am referring the CSS files in this sequence in my layout page:

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bucket-ico-fonts.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/datatable/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/datatable/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/BootstrapoSwitch/bootstrap-switch.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and my JS file is in this sequence:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.slimscroll.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/scripts.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/toastr.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/datatable/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/datatable/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/datatable/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/datatable/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/BootstrapSwitch/toggle-init.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/BootstrapSwitch/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
```

problem is when I write code like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BankName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-lg-3 col-sm-3 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BankName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BankName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is the output
[image: this is the output]

The textbox in `col-md-9` should display in full width...but not working.

Comment: Use your browser tools to inspect the css. You possibly have a `max-width` on the textbox

Comment: no text-box property of width:100%

Comment: Well what else is telling you (we cannot see it!)

Comment: there is no error in console

Comment: Of course there is no error - its css. You need to inspect the styles that are generated

Comment: So it was the `max-width` as per my first comment!

Comment: yes i forgot to give max-width to text-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works for me:

```
input{
max-width: 100%;
resize: none;
overflow: hidden;
```

}